# Рефлексия или создание объекта "обычным" способом?

Tags: java, база-данных, jdbc

В одном из примеров использования JDBC приводится следующая инициализация драйвера базы данных:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

Как я понимаю, с тем же успехом может быть использовано создание объекта драйвера "обычным" способом:

```
new org.postgresql.Driver();
```

Чем оправдано в данном случае использование рефлексии, в чем состоит отличие двух представленных здесь способов и какой из них следует предпочесть? И вообще, есть ли какая-либо разница в ходе выполнения программы при использовании каждого из этих способов?

Comment: Да, спасибо, исправил. Кстати, попробовал сейчас вообще не регистрировать драйвер никаким из указанных способов - и все работает. Достаточно указания пути к драйверу в CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использование метода `Class.forName` не приводит к созданию экземпляра класса, а только к загрузке класса и инициализации его статической части. Поэтому это не то же самое что создать экземпляр этого класса.

Сама инициализация в случае драйвера БД нужна, чтобы в классе был выполнен статический блок, который условно выглядит так:

```
static {
    try {
        java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.postgresql.Driver());
    } catch (SQLException E) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't register driver!");
    }
}
```

и который нужен для регистрация драйвера в `DriverManager` с помощью метода [registerDriver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#registerDriver(java.sql.Driver)).

Однако инициализация класса с помощью `Class.forName` требовалась только в старых версиях JDBC (до 4.0). С версии 4.0 это уже не требуется, так как для этого [теперь используется](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) файл

```
META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver
```

Подробный ответ можно посмотреть на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8053125/3432401).